# Syncing Thunderbird Profiles Between Win10 Ubuntu 20.04 on Dual-Boot Machines

Tags: ubuntu, sync, thunderbird

Now that Thunderbird has fully integrated Lightning Calendar.  Might someone be willing t post a definitive/updated guide to sharing an Ubuntu 20.04 Thunderbird profile with a Win10 Thunderbird client on a different partition? The best article that I have found seems to be out-dated.  http://web.archive.org/web/20050207141558/http://texturizer.net/thunderbird/share_mail.html

Thanks.

Comment: When running Ubuntu you can't access Windows partition files? I wondering why not use the same profiles folder?

Comment: You are right. Memory a bit rusty, haven't had to play with windows in a long time... thanks.